# "____ monkey" by Dubois? Help!

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a sci-fi/fantasy short story by an author named Dubois.

It's called "___________ monkey" but I can't remember the first word. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give any details about the story? It might help in finding it.

Answer (score 10):

Searching on the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) turned up a story called [Etoundi's Monkey](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48171), by Judith Dubois. The listing says it's available in the anthology [Under African Skies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0886775442).

A [goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/109593606) describes it thusly;

> *An alien baby is found, & the ownership disputed among a medicine man,
> an old woman, & a Japanese exchange student. Very good; a surprise
> ending!*